# How to use middle min-height element when its contents is long

Tags: html, css, height

(1) When #child2's contents is short, I want to display output like this:

[image]

https://output.jsbin.com/nisacihuru

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">child</div>
    <div id="child2">
        <div id="child2_1">child2_1</div>
        <div id="child2_2">child2_2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="child3">child3</div>
</div>

body, html { height: 100% }

#parent { height: 1px; min-height: 100% }

#child { height: 20%; background-color: red; }
#child2 { height: 1px; min-height: 80%; }
#child2_1 { height: 50%; background-color: orange; }
#child2_2 { min-height: 50%; background-color: yellow; }
#child3 { height: 20%; background-color: green; }
```

(2) and when #child2's contents is long, I want to display output like this.

[image]

https://output.jsbin.com/nunosodaju

`<div id="child2_2">child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br></div>`

but it doesn't work well..  in second case, the #child3's contents goes on the #child2_2.

If you know that, please explain how to solve it. thanks :)

Comment: `height: 1px; min-height: 80%;` remove height: 1px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#child {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#child2 {
  flex: 4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child2_1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}

#child2_2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#child3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">child</div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="child2_1">child2_1</div>
    <div id="child2_2">child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br>child2_2<br></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3">child3</div>
</div>
```